# Random variables transformation Normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> if $x_1,x_2,...,x_{20}$ are iid $N(0,4)$, what is the distribution of
>
> 1. $x^2$
> 2. ${{\sum_{i = 1}^5 {{x_i}^2} } \over {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{10} {{x_i}^2} }}$

my attempt for (1):

$$\begin{align}E({e^{tx^2}}) &= \int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {{1 \over {2\sqrt {2\pi } }}} {e^{t{x^2} - {1 \over 8}{x^2}}}dx \\
&= \int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {{1 \over {2\sqrt {2\pi } }}} {e^{ - ({{1 - 8t} \over 8}){x^2}}}dx = \left({1 \over {1 - 8t}}\right)^{{1 \over 2}}
\end{align} 
$$
so the distribution is $\operatorname{Gamma}\left({1 \over 2},8\right)$.

as for (2):
$$
  {{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^5 {{x_i}^2} } \over {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{10} {{x_i}^2} }} = {{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^5 {{x_i}^2} } \over {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^5 {{x_i}^2}  + \,\sum\limits_{i = 6}^{10} {{x_i}^2} }}$$

which is $\operatorname{Beta}\left({5 \over 2},{5 \over 2}\right)$.

Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. indicating $X\sim N(0;4)$ usually $N(\mu;\sigma^2)$ is meant.

Thus, as

$$\frac{X}{2}\sim \Phi$$

$$\frac{X^2}{4}\sim\chi_{(1)}^2=Gamma\Bigg(\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}\Bigg)$$

that is also

$$X^2\sim Gamma(\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{8})$$

---

**EDIT**: your answer is correct. The only difference with mine is that I use the following parametrization

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}y^{\alpha-1}e^{-y\beta}$$

While you use this one

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^{\alpha}}y^{\alpha-1}e^{-\frac{y}{\beta}}$$

Thus the two answers are the same

---

2. Correct.
3. Do not forget that

$X_1,X_2,\dots ,X_{20}$ are random variables, thus a Capital letter is required.

Comment: @Ahmed : I am reviewing your answer and it is correct. The difference with mine is only a different parametrization of Gamma distribution

Comment: thank you very much